# destructuring arguments in a group of constructors in JS

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, destructuring

How can I 1) pass the prototype props from parent-constructor to child-constructors, 2) using destructure to organice the parameters of all my constructors,  without causing a Type error?

this is the code I want to fix:

```
function Participant ({gender, age, tastes, education}){
  this.gender = gender;
  this.age = age; 
  this.tastes = tastes || [];
  this.education = education || 0;
}

function Payer(gender, age, tastes, education, income, job){
  this.base = Participant;
  this.base(gender, age, tastes, education); 
  this.income = income;
  this.job = job || 'merchant';
}
Payer.prototype = new Participant;

function NotPayer({gender, age, tastes, role}){
  this.role = role || 'kid';
  this.base = Participant;
  this.job = 'Not Valid';
  this.base(gender, age, tastes);
}
NotPayer.prototype = new Payer;

const kid1 = new NotPayer({role: 'nephew', age: 6, gender: 'male', tastes: ['ps4', 'golf']});
kid1.role;// 'nephew'
const kid2 = new Participant({gender: 'female'});
kid2.gender; // Type Error: Cannot destructure property 'gender' of 'undefined'
```

What I tried to fix it is this:

```
function Participant ({gender, age, tastes, education}){
  this.gender = gender;
  this.age = age; 
  this.tastes = tastes || [];
  this.education = education || 0;
}

function Payer(gender, age, tastes, education, income, job){
  this.base = Participant;
  this.base(gender, age, tastes, education);
  this.income = income;
  this.job = job || 'merchant';
}
//Payer.prototype = new Participant;

function NotPayer({gender, age, tastes, role}){
  this.role = role || 'kid';
  this.base = Participant;
  this.job = 'Not Valid';
  this.base(gender, age, tastes);
}
//NotPayer.prototype = new Payer;

const kid1 = new NotPayer({role: 'nephew', age: 6, gender: 'male', tastes: ['ps4', 'golf']});
console.log(kid1.role); // nephew
const kid2 = new Participant({gender: 'female'});
console.log(kid2.gender); // female
```

It works only because I'm commenting the expression to assign the parent-constructor to the child-constructors (as a consequence, for example, `kid1.gender` becomes `undefined`)

**To note** that The code manage to use both, Parent prototype inheritance and parameter destructuring, only in the following case (when using destructuring just in the last constructor child):

```
function Participant (gender, age, tastes, education){
  this.gender = gender;
  this.age = age; 
  this.tastes = tastes || [];
  this.education = education || 0;
}
function NotPayer({gender, age, tastes, role}){
  this.role = role || 'kid';
  this.base = Participant;
  this.job = 'Not Valid';
  this.base(gender, age, tastes);//check education
}
NotPayer.prototype = new Participant;

const kid1 = new NotPayer({role: 'nephew', age: 6, gender: 'male', tastes: ['ps4', 'golf']});
console.log(kid1.gender); // male

console.log(NotPayer.prototype); // Participant{...}
```

Thanks!!
and sorry about the extent of this question.

Comment: If you are going to use ES6 destructuring syntax, then use the `class` syntax too, which provides the `extends` syntax for prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Thanks trincot! May I ask you to help us with the discussion below? You are more experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Participant {
  constructor(gender, age, tastes, education) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.tastes = tastes || [];
    this.education = education || 0;
  }
}

class NotPayer extends Participant {
  constructor({gender, age, tastes, role}) {
    super(gender, age, tastes)
    this.role = role || 'kid';
    this.job = 'Not Valid';
  }
}

const kid1 = new NotPayer({role: 'nephew', age: 6, gender: 'male', tastes: ['ps4', 'golf']});
console.log(kid1.gender)

console.log(NotPayer.prototype)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Why `NotPayer.prototype` is an empty object (I was expecting that was to log the Participant constructor)?

Comment: Is it?  I am having the following line in log

`Participant {constructor: ƒ}`

as output of `console.log(NotPayer.prototype)`

You?

Comment: I have `NotPayer {}` in node, for `console.log(NotPayer.prototype);`

Comment: How `console.log` outputs an object is dependent on the environment. Certain is that `.prototype` is a prototype object, not the constructor. Do `console.log(NotPayer.prototype.constructor)`, and you'll get the function `NotPayer`.